Selecting (or removing) elements at the sublist level
I have tried all manner of combinations of Select/Map etc etc to do the following simple task. Needless to say I haven't stumbled upon the answer except in a clunky way.
Given the following list with 3 sublists of differing length - how do I select or preferentially remove the numbers less than or equal to zero. In the code box below I start with nested list mC and would like a nested list mD as shown.
Now I know how to do this for a list using select but not with a nested list. And what I want to avoid is using three separate Select on each sublist at a time and then combining those back into a nested sublist.
mC = {{-10,-9,-8,-1,0,1,8,9,10},{-108,-54,0,54,108},{-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5}}

mD = {{1,8,9,10},{54,108},{1,2,3,4,5}}

EDIT: What exactly was off topic or a simple syntax error?

Have you thought about using ReplaceAll instead? mC /. _?NonPositive -> Nothing

@Domen Er, No. Otherwise I'd have solved the problem LOL. Thanks for that. What I was doing was trying to Map Select at the nested level but nothing worked.

Also, using the operator form of Select: Select[# > 0 &] /@ list. Generally, if the lists are at Level n in the nested list, you can do Map[Select[# > 0 &], list, n].

Similarly to How to filter a list with no strings elements, you can use:
DeleteCases
DeleteCases[mC, _?NonPositive, All]

ReplaceAll
mC /. _?NonPositive -> Nothing

Pick
Pick[mC, Positive[mC]]

If you have a nested list with fixed depth, you can also use Select + Map
Map[Select[Positive], mC]
(* or generally *)
Map[Select[Positive], mC, {depth}]


much appreciated. Always nice to see a multitude of approaches to the same thing.

mC = {{-10, -9, -8, -1, 0, 1, 8, 9, 10}, {-108, -54, 0, 54, 
   108}, {-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}

Pick[mC, Sign[mC], 1]
SequenceReplace[#, {a_?NonPositive} :> Nothing] & /@ mC
SequenceCases[#, {a_?Positive} :> a] & /@ mC



{{1, 8, 9, 10}, {54, 108}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}


Thanks for that approach. Not sure why the question was closed though. List manipulation is very important in Mathematica and I couldn't find anything that close to what I asked so I see it being useful. Oh well.
